Iv'e lost write access to dual booted windows since reinstalling xubuntu
For a long while I had xubuntu and windows dual booted and I decided to reinstall a fresh xubuntu.
As a result of that I have lost write access to windows.
How do I regain access please?

I have also lost access to 'games' and 'my data'drive in a similar way. Perhaps access can be gained similarly?



This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

make a mount point for each nvme: sudo mkdir/name of mount point
Using blkid command find UUID for each nvme
make /etc/fstab entry for each nvme:
If ext formatted drive:
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1c48a4ef-44cc-4905-ba94-abdefd677e8e /media/nvme-data ext4 defaults 0 0
If ntfs formatted drive:
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1c48a4ef-44cc-4905-ba94-abdefd677e8e /media/nvme-data  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
Check syntax before restarting computer:
sudo mount -a
If result is blank should ok to reboot otherwise deal with any mounting error.
